# An internal error occurred during: "Launching MyFirstApp". com/android/ide/eclipse/adt/internal/launchController

Tags: android, eclipse

I just purchased a new laptop (Windows 8.1) and I'm testing it to see how it will perform with Android Development...so I downloaded and installed the Android SDK (ADT Bundle for Windows) from android.developers.com.

As a quick test I entered the sample app "MyFirstApp" on the android.developers site, created a AVD (Nexus_4) from the template of devices provided in AVD...and then attempted to run the app. Unfortunately this is where I get a "Problem Occured" popup with the following message:

"An internal error occurred during: "Launching MyFirstApp". com/android/ide/eclipse/adt/internal/launchController"

I checked other questions/responses posted...none of the others found seemed to apply to my situation.

BTW, after it didn't run with the Nexus_4 AVD..I tried it with another AVD template (Nexus Samsung) and got the same failure.

Adding more information:

I installed the 64-bit version of SDK...again running Windows 8.1.
Also here is the exception stack trace associated with Internal error message noted above.

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/android/ide/eclipse/adt/internal/launch/AndroidLaunchController
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.launch.LaunchConfigDelegate.launch(LaunchConfigDelegate.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:855)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:704)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin.buildAndLaunch(DebugUIPlugin.java:1047)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin$8.run(DebugUIPlugin.java:1251)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)

Regards,
Jet

Answer (score 0):

I was hoping that I had made some silly mistake and someone would quickly recognize it and recommend an easy fix to my problem. Unfortunately I didn't get a response so I just tried repeating a number of my prior steps..1) Re-creating AVDs; 2) Reinstalling the entire SDK; 3) Installing Windows 8.1 updates;

Ultimately it is working now..but I'm not sure what the problem was or what the fix was but it is working now.

BTW, as noted above in my question I'm using the 64 bit version of SDK (and I'm using 64bit version of JDK).

Cheers,
Jet